# Spring 18 Scratch orgs

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, spring18

I need to start testing the new url scheme which will be introduced in the Spring 18 Release. When will we be able to create scratch orgs using Spring 18?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already possible: You can create a [Spring '18 Enterprise Edition Pre-Release org](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring18.jsp) that you'll use as your DevHub to create Spring '18 Scratch Org, as explained by the PM Rohit Mehta [here](https://twitter.com/rohitforce/status/950569141467041793).